# replicate log option

Tags: integration, finance

definition of a log contract: 
A log contract on a stock $S_t$ with strike $K$ is a European derivative with expiry $T$ and payoff function $V(S_T, \tau = 0) = \log(S_T/K), K > 0$ where $\tau = (T-t)$ is the time to expiration of the contract.

If I want to hedge (i.e., replicate) this contract I can crate a portfolio $\Pi$ as continuum of call and put options with strikes $y$.

At expiry, the payoff of this  replicating portfolio is
$$\Pi(S_T, (T-t) = 0)= \int_0^K \underbrace{(y - S_T)^{+}}_{puts} \frac{dy}{y^2}+ \int_K^\infty\underbrace{(S_T - y)^{+}}_{calls} \frac{dy}{y^2}= I_1 + I_2$$

with the integrals given as
\begin{align*}
  I_1 &= \Bigg[ - \log(S_T/K) + \frac{S_T - K}{K} \Bigg] 1_{\{S_T < K\}} \\
  I_2 &= \Bigg[ - \log(S_T/K) + \frac{S_T - K}{K} \Bigg] 1_{\{S_T > K\}}
\end{align*}

My question is now, how are those integrals calculated? I am having trouble in particular with the indicator functions, when rewriting $(y-S_T)^{+} = (y - S_T) 1_{\{y > S_T\}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just do the casework.  Obviously, if $S_T > K$, then the integrand for $I_1$ is zero for all $0 < y \le K$, since $(y - S_T)^+ = 0$ if $y \le S_T$.  So $I_1 = 0$ if $S_T > K$.  Similarly, $I_2 = 0$ if $S_T < K$.

Consequently, we consider the case where $0 \le S_T < K$ for $I_1$, which simplifies the integral as follows:

$$\begin{align}I_1
&= \int_{y=0}^K (y - S_T)^+ \frac{dy}{y^2} \\
&= \int_{y=S_T}^K \frac{y-S_T}{y^2} \, dy \\
&= \int_{y=S_T}^K \frac{1}{y} \, dy - S_T \int_{y=S_T}^K \frac{1}{y^2} \, dy \\
&= \Bigl[\log y \Bigr]_{y=S_T}^K - S_T \left[-\frac{1}{y}\right]_{y=S_T}^K \\
&= \log \frac{K}{S_T} + S_T \left(\frac{1}{K} - \frac{1}{S_T}\right) \\
&= - \log \frac{S_T}{K} + \frac{S_T - K}{K}.
\end{align}$$
The only thing left to do is reintroduce the indicator function, which applies because the above calculation is valid only when $S_T < K$.

The calculation of $I_2$ follows similarly and is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much @heropup, I apperently just made a mess with the cases. Much appreciated.